# Was sent a code.on discord

Tags: cipher, treasure-hunt

`54 68 61 74 20 77 61 73 20 73 69 6d 70 6c 65 2e 20 42 75 74 20 6e 6f 77 20 69 73 20 74 68 65 20 74 69 6d 65 20 74 6f 20 68 75 6e 74 2e 20 33 38 2e 36 32 32 35 32 30 39 2c 2d 31 32 31 2e 33 36 35 38 31 37 36 2c`
I've tried using hex, but that didn't work.
If it helps, I was sent it by "b9sguy#8764"
If you could solve it, thanks.

Comment: Are you *sure* you tried hexadecimal? Deusovi was apparently able to translate it without any problem.

Comment: Just paste it in a simple hex to ascii converter (https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) and you'll get `That was simple. But now is the time to hunt. 38.6225209,-121.3658176,`.

Answer (score 5):

This is simple hexadecimal for

> `That was simple. But now is the time to hunt. 38.6225209,-121.3658176,`

Those coordinates lead to

> a place [just outside a building in Eastern Oak Park](https://www.google.com/maps/place/38%C2%B037'21.1%22N+121%C2%B021'56.9%22W/@38.622579,-121.365922,21z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d38.6225209!4d-121.3658176), Sacramento, California.

Comment: You may want to explain how it was done as Mr. Confused tried hex and failed, so it was not a simple solution but a lession. A quick nodge: 54 in hex is is 84 in decimal (windows calculator can do this), now check out an ascii table on the web to see which letter is encoded with which dec. Or... find an ascii table with hex on it and skip the dec part. :D